# android fragment orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, android-dialogfragment

**EDIT:**

I have a `DialogFragment` where the reference inside the parent `Activity` is NULL after I change device orientation. How do I fix this?

Fragment creation:

```
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(title);
myFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), tag);
```

After orientation change:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
myFragment.dismiss();  //NULL pointer exception here
```

Comment: We need to see more code and get more info in order to have any chance of helping you. How do you create the fragment? Do you do anything to handle orientation update?

Comment: Can you find the fragment from the tag before orientation change?

Comment: I am relying on the default system behaviour to handle the orientation change

Comment: You can also make sure that the tag you use to create the fragment is the same as the one you use to search? Is the Dialog fragment gone after the orientation change?

Comment: @Marco Yes, I am using the same tag and the fragment is visible after change. The findFragmentByTag method works fine if I don't change orientation. It seems as if when the orienation change happens and the fragment is recreated by the system, it does not have the tag I used.

Comment: Are you want to do something after orientation changes? If not, just add android:configChange="orientation" in the manifest, override it in your fragment the method onConfigurationChanged() remove super.onConfigurationChange() and do nothing there. And also set .setRetainInstance(true) when instantionating the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myFragment.setRetainInstance(true);` for the rescue.

---

**Edit:**

Also Override `onDestroyView` in your DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
  if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
    getDialog().setOnDismissListener(null);
  super.onDestroyView();
}
```

This is a result of the following issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17423